# Данные за последную минуту

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать записи за последнюю минуту?
Есть поле datetime:

```
2017-02-08 15:12:36.000
2017-02-08 15:12:15.000
2017-02-08 15:11:49.000
```

Comment: запрос то ваш где?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями `getdate()` дающую текущую дату/время. И [`dateadd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186819.aspx) прибавляющую к дате нужную величину (`MI` - минуты, количество -1).

```
select *
  from Tab
 where datetime_field > dateadd(MI,-1,getdate())
```